# How to read csv file and point its content to variables?

Tags: csv, go

I am trying to read csv file in golang and point its content to variables for query and writing output to new csv file. The content in csv looks like:

```
1,google.com
2,netflix.com
3,api-global.netflix.com
4,www.google.com
5,facebook.com
6,microsoft.com
7,doubleclick.net
```

And so on, about 10,000,000 lines.

My code is as below

```
func main() {
    qnamecsv,_:=os.Open("top-1m.csv")
    reader:=bufio.NewReader(qnamecsv)
    for {
      line,_,_:=reader.ReadLine()
        fmt.Println("%s",line)
    }
    var nameserver string = "8.8.8.8"
    var qname string = "hostname from qname csv"
```

How can I write new file now? Thanks for any help

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Look at packages: either standard https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv or if you need extra options https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv

It gives you a way to define a structure and load csv file into it.

```
type Site struct {
      ID int
      Domain string
 }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/NykL1O5Wfh